# What is the .var folder for in my Home Directory

Tags: filesystem, home-directory, 21.04

What is the `~/.var` folder used for and is it safe to remove the content within this folder?

Comment: If you have anything installed via flatpak, `~/.var/app` contains those apps' cache and data files.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, `/var` contains variable data files. This can include spool directories and files, administrative and logging data, and transient and temporary files.

Since it's under your home directory, it's probably safe to assume that files under `~/.var` serve the same purpose as files under `/var` except that they are for your user only.

Perhaps an application that you use is storing important files there.  You can certainly inspect the files yourself.

A good rule of thumb is that if you don't know what something does in a system or config folder, it's best to leave it alone.

Answer (score 13):

The ~/.var directory is normally used for [Flatpak](https://flatpak.org), since it stores its installed programs and their data. But, it could also be another program that's writing into that directory. Hope this helps.

Comment: Should it be a part of the "home backup" or it is safe to skip it?

Comment: The flatpak applications could store their configurations there but otherwise they should be safe to skip in backups.